# Adding emission to hair shader

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, shader-nodes, emission

Houdini 20 has a new fur shader incorporating the medulla, a structure within animal fur that makes it appear softer and more volume-like than human hair. Can the emission node be connected to Blender's hair shader output as a volume, to emulate the medulla?

[image: Medulla]

[image: FurShaderComparison]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can connect an emmission shader into the volume output, it will give a somewhate softer look to the hair

here is an example using [blender studio's demo file](https://www.blender.org/download/demo/geometry-nodes/hair_nodes-animal_fur_examples.blend)
[image]

[image]